# Express for windows 8 vs Express for windows desktop

Tags: visual-studio-2012

On the Visual Studio Express 2012 page there are 2 options: *Express for Windows 8* and *Express for Windows Desktop*

What are the differences between these two?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Express for Windows 8 edition only supports developing programs for the Windows Store.  Your program will only run on Win8 on a desktop machine or Windows RT slate and must be distributed through the Store.

Express for Windows Desktop edition lets you develop programs that run on the regular Windows desktop, the way programs on Windows have been running for the past 20 years.