# How do I code Visual Basic Express 2010 programs in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I downloaded Visual Studio 2013 for my new computer but I am being told I can't use programs I made in Visual Basic 2010, and that 2013 is only for Windows Store apps... How do I use 2010 programs in the 2013 version?

Comment: You need VB Express for Desktop apps

Comment: possible duplicate of [Express for windows 8 vs Express for windows desktop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504324/express-for-windows-8-vs-express-for-windows-desktop)

Comment: Oh ok... I didn't notice there were two versions. Thanks guys! (How do I mark this as solved?)